# Erro ao tentar gerar Scaffolding

Tags: visual-studio, scaffold

Estou tentando gerar um `Scaffolfing` para o model abaixo:

```
    namespace OneeWeb_v2.Models
{
    public class CombustivelModels
    {
        [Key]
        public int CombustivelId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public decimal km_inicial { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public decimal km_final { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public decimal litros { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal valor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Porem ao tentar executar é retornado o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem saberia me dizer porque?

Comment: As vezes é necessário realizar um **Build** para o scaffolding funcionar. Clique com o botão direito em cima do projeto e clique em **Build**.

Comment: Perfeito. funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro é bem claro. Ele diz que seu modelo não possui uma **Key** definida, ou seja, o VS não entendeu que sua classe **CombustivelModels** possua uma primary key. O motivo disso pode ser algumas coisas, tipo:

- Não está utilizando o Atributo `[Key]`ou Fluent API;
- O nome do modelo não segue a padronização de **NomeClasse + Id** ou somente **Id**;

Podemos ver em seu código que esse não é o problema, pois você está utilizando o Atributo `[Key]`.

Porém, você deve ter adicionado esse atributo antes de dar **Build** no sistema pela última vez. Se esse for o caso, basta clicar com o botão direito em cima da solução e clicar em **Build**.